# How to abstract 3rd party implementation details from the core functionality?

Tags: python, paradigms

Here is an example of the problem and requirement .

**Scenario** : We have a Web App , The Controller has a function that does HTML to PDF conversion . We have to switch to various engines depending on the requirement and advancement in Technology . This means we need to keep changing the core file . It can even be a web service that does my job and not implemented locally .

Overall the current architecture in pseudo Python is  :

Controller

```
def requestEntry():
    """Entry point"""
    html = REQUEST['html'] , css = REQUEST['css']
    createPDF(html,css)

def createPDF(html,css):
    """Sigh"""
    #Hardcoding Begines
    configured_engine  = getXMLOption('configured_engine')
    if configured_engine == "SuperPDFGen":
       #Returns SuperGen's PDF Blob
       supergen = SuperGen(html,css)
       return supergen.pdfout() 
    if configured_engine = "PISA":
       pisa = PISA(html,css)
       return pisa.pdf_out()
```

**The problem here is every new engine requirement is a code change in the controller .And suppose we find a new technology we have to upgrade the core software version .**

**Solving it :**

One way I can think of is to define a simple class like this :

```
def createPdf(data,engine):
    pdf_render = PDFRender(html,css,engine)
    return pdf_render.pdf_out()
```

So now we keep out PDFRender astracted - core version need not be changed any more for a implemetation change   , but we need to code the engines with a If ladder in the PDFRender Class .

To extend this idea , i could have a convention engine would be the module name too . But this own't adapt to a URL if its given as Engine .

```
def createPdf(data,engine):
    #Convert the string called engine to a Module ! Sigh 
    import engine Engine!!
    pdf_render = engine.Engine(data)
    return pdf_render()
```

Are there any suggested paradigm's or a plugin adapter mechanism for this? It should take a URL or a Python Module as input and get the job done . New implementations should be standalone and pluggable to the existing code with no version changes in core feature . How can I do that ? I think the core should talk in terms of service (either a python module , sub process or a url ) this is what I trying to achieve .

Comment: plugin design may help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323202/designing-extensible-software-plugin-architecture is a link for plugin architecture .

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface is amazing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a package where you stick your renderers, one Python module for each, the module being named after the "engine" and the renderer class being named "PDFRenderer". Then in the package's `__init__` scan the modules in the directory, import the `PDFRenderer` class from each module, and build a enginename:PDFRenderer mapping, and use it to get the `PDFRenderer` class for the engine.

Comment: That means approach ? However the __init__ scan is a new concept thanks . Now the only caveat I see if the engine is a URL - completely a webservice based solution .

Comment: You then wrap the webservice client in the `PDFRenderer` and just pass the engine name instead of the service url. You _will_ have engine-dependant options to set anyway, won't you ?

Comment: Correct few engine dependent settings might be there here and there but that's not in PDFRender it would be in the Product Module . Basically the good thing is its HTML5 + CSS input and PDF output , so we have some specifications already which is why we can abstract it .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like right now you have to change a couple of lines of code each time you change pdf renderer. The code is simple and easy to understand.

Sure, you can abstract it all out, and use configuration files, and add a plugin architecture. But what will you gain? Instead of changing a couple of lines of code, you'll instead change a plugin or a configuration file, and that machinery will need to be maintained: for example, if you decide you need to pass in some flags to one of the renderers, then you have to add that functionality to your configuration file or whatever abstraction you've chosen.

How many times do you think you'll change pdf renderer? My guess would be at most once a year. Keep your code simple, and don't build complex solutions until you really need them.

Comment: Interesting perspective , I did think about that too . So you are recommending the approach 1 in Solutions . The first is trashed because we end up changing core version all the time .