# How to get object from a OSGI container?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

For Example : to use OSGI framework , I develop a connection pool to connect a system , and now I have another program want to connect the system , but I want to get the connection from the connection pool , how can I do to get the connection from the pool ?

Comment: maybe it's just me, but I have no clue what this is about... does this happen inside the same JVM?

Comment: no, they are not in the same JVM ?

Comment: the answers to this question might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375725/how-does-osgi-manage-interaction-of-components-running-in-separate-jvms

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an OSGi framework from a regular java application, and then access a service exposed from the OSGi environment to the 'host' application, I suggest you take a look at the "Using Services Provided by Bundles" section of [the Apache Felix manual](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html#ApacheFelixFrameworkLaunchingandEmbedding-hostinteraction). It's not hard as long as you get the class loading right.

If that is not what you meant, please clarify.

Regards, Frank