# What problem does Peaberry for Guice solve?

Tags: osgi, libraries, guice, peaberry

I understand the problem that OSGI solved thanks to this question....

[What does OSGi solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106222/what-does-osgi-solve)

And I am already convinved that Guice is amazing so I'm curious what this OSGI integration for Guice known as "peaberry" is supposed to do, it seems to be popping up everywhere, even in Maven 3 presentations.

http://code.google.com/p/peaberry/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It extends Guice to allow injection of OSGi services.

Answer (score 6):

It basically allows you to provide and consume OSGi services by binding this into your Guice modules. You could use plain Guice without Peaberry inside OSGi, but it's much easier to use Peaberry for this.

I myself prefer to use Peaberry with it's activation extensions so that I do not need any BundleActivator code in my bundles. This is very similar to be using Spring Dynamic Modules, except that it's all java and typesafe.